# Python Output Snowflake Connector To CSV

Tags: python, sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently am trying to print the output of a snowflake connector query and write it to csv, but I'm having issues doing this. Currently, my code example looks like:

```
query = '''SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE;'''

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user='XXXX',
                                   password='XXXX',
                                   account='XXXX')

query_output = conn.cursor().execute(query)
```

Is there a way for me to print the output of the query, like maybe `print(query_output)` and then also write it to csv like `query_output.to_csv(path)`?

Comment: Just curious, after writing are you going to import it in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)' DataFrames API. Amongst several other data transformation and analysis capabilities, it has an excellent CSV reader and writer implementation that is [very flexible](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv).

Snowflake's Python Connector also [natively supports](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#fetch_pandas_all) transforming results as Pandas DataFrame objects.

A very simple, adapted example is provided below (1 added line):

```py
query = '''SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE;'''

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user='XXXX',
                                   password='XXXX',
                                   account='XXXX')

query_output = conn.cursor().execute(query)

## You may have to run: pip3 install --user pandas ##

query_output.fetch_pandas_all().to_csv("/path/to/write/table.csv")
```

The default CSV formatting uses `,` as the separator, OS-specific newlines (`\n` except on Windows, which uses `\r\n`), and minimal quoting (auto-quotes `VARCHAR` columns that carry delimiter characters within them).

Comment: You need to install Pandas with this command `pip install "snowflake-connector-python[pandas]"`. Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-pandas#installation

Comment: @anyfactor Or just `pip install pyarrow` if you already have Pandas, as implied with the error message `snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 255002: Optional dependency: 'pyarrow' is not installed, please see the following link for install instructions: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#installation`.

Comment: This solution and the csv module one seem about as efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this :

```
import csv
.....
.....
.....
rows = cur.fetchall()
column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
with open('samplefile.csv', 'w') as fp:
  myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator = '\n')
  myFile.writerow(column_names)
  myFile.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: This solution and the Pandas one seem about as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to print the results. To save it in csv, just save the results in a dataframe using for loop and then use df.to_csv

```
    cursor.execute(query)
    sql_result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(sql_result)     ## just print the results or use the for loop below to print the results row by row 
    for row in sql_result:
        print(row)
```