# how load excel file using python into snowflake table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i need to load excel file from the shared folder using PYTHON into snowflake table, Once data is loaded into snowflake table  i need to create three CSV file from it using PYTHON.

how to do it

tired using code to read data from excel but do not know how to load into snowflake

Comment: Hi - as this is not a free code writing service, what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can try to use Pandas to get the data from the excel file which you can then [load into Snowflake using this guide](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-pandas). Afterwards you can [use the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070384/python-output-snowflake-connector-to-csv) to output to a csv.